# Locate member of a structure

Tags: assembly, struct, offset, pointer

In an assembly line, I have a call to `gethostbyname(...)`. I have read that the return value of that function can be a pointer to a `hostent` structure
(of course, it could be also a null pointer but for my question I need the pointer to the hostent structure)

I also take a look to the hostent structure which is the following:

```
   typedef struct hostent{
    char FAR *h_name;
    char FAR FAR **h_aliases;
    short h_addrtype;
    short h_length;
    char FAR FAR **h_addr_list;
   } HOSTENT, *PHOSTENT, FAR *LPHOSTENT;
```

So, some lines later the following appears:

```
  mov edx, [eax+0Ch]
```

I know that the return value of a function is stored in `eax`. So, when `eax` points to `hostent` structure, then `edx` must point to one of the `hostent` structure `members`, because the offset is `0Ch`.

To determine which of the member it is, i know that I must count the sizes of the members. And here comes my question:

> When I count until I reach the offset `0Ch`, which of these types I must take? I mean, when you look at the first member, for example:
>
> ```
> char FAR *h_name;
> ```
>
> Is the size of `char` relevant or the size of `FAR` ? Or both ?

I hope someone can explain me that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FAR` is just an attribute, not a data type.  Not even a standard attribute, but an attribute that was introduced with MS-DOS C compilers, to distinguish between 16-bit and 32-bit pointers, and carried over to windows 16 bit, windows 32 bit and, recently, windows 64 bit.

What is stored in the structure is a pointer to a character (in fact, an array of characters), which has 4 bytes (in the case of a 32 bit program), or 8 bytes (in the case of a 64 bit program). You don't tell which you have, but `mov edx, [eax+0Ch]` implies 32 bit, as 64 bit registers have names like `rdx` and `rax`. So, your structure has this layout (note you also need to know `short`s have 16 bit):

```
offset   bytes bits member
00-03    4     32   h_name
04-07    4     32   h_aliases
08-09    2     16   h_addrtype
0a-0b    2     16   h_length
0c-0f    4     32   h_addr_list
```

Note that it's not always that easy, because [compilers may introduce padding bytes between struct members for alignment reasons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment). If you have access to a C compiler, the safest thing is to use [offsetof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof):

```
printf("%02x\n", offsetof(struct hostent, h_addr_list));
```

Answer (score 1):

A sample walkthrough containing few lines of code compiled in msvc++exp and windbagged in 32 bit machine

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    WSADATA wsaData;    
    in_addr addr;
    hostent *myhost;
        if ((WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData)) == 0)
        if ( ( myhost = gethostbyname("www.google.com") ) != NULL) {
            printf("host name = %s\n",myhost->h_name);
            if (myhost->h_addrtype == AF_INET) {
                addr.s_addr = *(u_long *) myhost->h_addr_list[0];
                printf("IPv4 Addr = %s\n",inet_ntoa(addr));
            }
        }    
        return 0;
}
```

run the compiled exe in windbg with a conditional break point as below
explanation being

```
break when ws2_32!gethostbyname is called
gu is to go up back to caller (eax will hold * to hostent structure)
display the structure pointed by eax with a c++ expression evaluator  ?? and quit
```

.

```
:\>cdb -c "bp ws2_32!gethostbyname \"gu ; r eax; ?? (hostent *) @eax;q\";g" ghostbyname.exe    
0:000> cdb: Reading initial command 'bp ws2_32!gethostbyname "gu ; r eax; ?? (ho
stent *) @eax;q";g'
eax=0016c3b8
struct hostent * 0x0016c3b8
   +0x000 h_name           : 0x0016c3f8  "www.google.com"
   +0x004 h_aliases        : 0x0016c3c8  -> (null)
   +0x008 h_addrtype       : 0n2
   +0x00a h_length         : 0n4
   +0x00c h_addr_list      : 0x0016c3cc  -> 0x0016c3e4  "J}???"
quit:

:\>
```

windbg can also be used to ascertain size of individual members

```
0:000> ?? sizeof(((hostent *) @eax)->h_name)
unsigned int 4
0:000> ?? sizeof(((hostent *) @eax)->h_aliases)
unsigned int 4
0:000> ?? sizeof(((hostent *) @eax)->h_addrtype)
unsigned int 2
0:000> ?? sizeof(((hostent *) @eax)->h_length)
unsigned int 2
0:000> ?? sizeof(((hostent *) @eax)->h_addr_list)
unsigned int 4
0:000> ?? sizeof(hostent)
unsigned int 0x10
```

with sizes gleaned thus dumping it in raw format becomes easy to script in an unknown binary

```
r $t0 = ${$arg1}
.printf /D "<b>eax          \t%p </b>\n",@$t0
.printf /D "<b>hostent *    \t%p </b>\n",poi(@$t0)
.printf /D "<b>->h_name     \t%ma</b>\n",poi(@$t0)
.printf /D "<b>->h_alias    \t%p </b>\n",poi(poi(@$t0+0x4))
.printf /D "<b>->h_addrtype \t%p </b>\n",low(poi(@$t0+0x8))
.printf /D "<b>->h_length   \t%p </b>\n",hi(poi(@$t0+0x8))
.printf /D "<b>->h_addrlist \t%p </b>\n",poi(poi(@$t0+0xc))
.printf /D "<b>->h_addrlist contains ip address in network byte order</b>\n"
db poi(poi(@$t0+0xc)) l10
.printf /D "<b>Ipv4 Address of google.com %d.%d.%d.%d\n" , 

by(poi(poi(@$t0+0xc))),by(poi(poi(@$t0+0xc))+1),by(poi(poi(@$t0+0xc))+2),by(poi(poi(@$t0+0xc))+3)
```

result dumped in raw format without symbol support in an unknown binary

```
0:000> $$>a< ghostbyname.txt @eax

eax             0016c3b8 
hostent *       0016c3f8 
->h_name        www.google.com
->h_alias       00000000 
->h_addrtype    00000002 
->h_length      00000004 
->h_addrlist    0016c3e4 
->h_addrlist contains ip address in network byte order
0016c3e4  4a 7d ec d0 4a 7d ec d4-4a 7d ec d3 4a 7d ec d1  J}..J}..J}..J}..
Ipv4 Address of google.com 74.125.236.208
```